# What happens when your dog eats a lot of Galliprant?

Tags: dogs, medicines, new-medicine

I found an empty, chewed up bottle of Galliprant (20mg, maybe 20 tablets left) when I got home.  Should I do anything or be worried about an overdose?

My dogs seem completely normal (after 12 or more hours).  One is a Westie (16 lbs), and the other is a mutt (29 lbs), and they are both 14 years old.  The mutt likely has early stage kidney disease, a nodule on his liver, for which he takes Denamarin, "gunk" in his gall bladder, for which he takes Ursodiol, and back stiffness/pain, for which he is taking gabapentin, and Galliprant.

Comment: Accidentally gave my dog too much Galliprant called the manufacturer as suggested and they were fantastic! Answered all of my questions and were very thorough and all of their answers. Very happy with Elanco right now. And my dog is doing great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Galliprant website](https://www.galliprantfordogs.com/vet):

> Galliprant tested at up to approximately 15X the labeled dose for 9 months in healthy dogs.
>
> - Studied at up to approximately 15X the labeled 2 mg/kg dose for a 9-month duration in healthy dogs
> - No clinically significant changes in liver, kidney or coagulation parameters
> - No noticeable effects on food consumption, body weight, ECG, organ weight or hematology
> - In most situations, gastrointestinal disturbances were mild or slight and fairly infrequent
> - Neither treatment nor GI disturbance was associated with changes in appetite, appearance or demeanor of dogs

Depending on the weight of your dog he could be fine or become ill. I highly recommend calling the company as they have veterinarians on staff to direct you in the right direction for their product.

**ELANCO 1-888-545-5973**